# Calling php in server from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, function, call

There are few questions with this name but I want a simple example without lots of details.

There is a button on page, when I click, it must go to server and run a php file on the server. Below code is not working...

my html code (with js) is:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Do it</button>
<script type="text/javascript">

function myFunction(){
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open("GET","C:\testSample\sample.php",true);
    x.send();
    return false;
</script>
```

my php file is:

```
<?php
 echo "Hello world";
 ?>
```

Is it about the path of php file that I defined in js ?

Comment: I think you want to use a URL to `sample.php`, and not a filepath.

Comment: yes, you suppose to set server address, not physical

Comment: You can't send an AJAX request to the *file system*, it has to be to a *web server*.  You need to actually install PHP and some kind of web server.

Comment: hey thanks. there is already a server in production installed on IIS. when we write "http://prodserver/mod/page/view.php?id=130" on explorer it goes to the page including the button. Should I find the path of the php file from IIS manager on server ?

Comment: @abidinberkay: If `sample.php` is on that server then you'd use its HTTP address to access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) server because PHP file needs to be executed on web server rather than some local file location. Once you install you can specify the path like

```
x.open("GET","http://localhost/testSample/sample.php",true);
```

Comment: I modified the path as you suggested, but still the button does nothing, not writing "hello world". Do you think my js and php sysntax is correct ?

Comment: You have missed closing bracket of myFunction()

Comment: @abidinberkay: You're also not actually using the "hello world" response anywhere, so where do you even expect it to be printed?

Answer (score 0):

Your path be something like this:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","./Path/Here/books.xml", false);  //for relative urls

xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/Path/Here/books.xml", false); //for absolute urls
```